# Creating a database to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to set up a website. The website is a tool to help people find certain products. So they select there categories like TV then select the specification of what they want in the TV so like HD, LCD and so on. So I want to know how  can I make a database filled with the TVs that will be able to be queried to bring back the TV closest to the specification provided. Are SQL tables the answer and query them with PHP?

Comment: Yes. You need more research. Start with the Google keyword 'shopping cart'.

Comment: They're AN answer, not THE answer - there is no right answer to this. This isn't really a question suited to this format - you need to ask a specific question we can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, as stated in the comments, your question is very unspecific, but i - as a fan of php and mysql - would say that those are ONE good answer to create a website like that. you can get free software suites to help you with this endeavour, start experimenting on your home computer, learn and work and finally set up a "real" server. i advise to check out some tutorials for php & mysql. good luck!